# New line break in mailto is not working in react native iOS

Tags: react-native, mailto

Newline break with mailto is not working in react native iOS. `%0D%0A` is getting displayed instead of the new line. Has someone also faced this issue?

Code Snippet:

```
    <RoundedButton
              onPress={() => {
              
               const body = `Device: ${Platform.OS === "ios" ? "iOS" : "Android"}%0D%0APhone Number: ${userState.profile?.mobilePhone}%0D%0AEmail: ${userState.profile?.email}%0D%0A`
               Linking.openURL(
                `mailto:abc@gmail.com?body=${body}`
              )}}
            >
            </RoundedButton>
```

OutPut:

[image: email content]

Comment: You need to encode the string to be URL safe. Use `mailto:abc@gmail.com?=${encodeURIComponent(body)}`

Comment: Thanks, Zed, I tried this also but it displayed <BR> instead of the new line.

Comment: Later I found that it is an open bug with the new iOS.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681023

Answer (score 0):

Please write this way:

const body = `Device: ${Platform.OS === "ios" ? "iOS" : "Android"}` + '/n' + `Phone Number: ${userState.profile?.mobilePhone}` + '/n' + `Email: ${userState.profile?.email}` + '/n'...

Comment: Thanks, Nikita.
Still not working.
Output: iOS/n/Phone Number:6756777/n

Code: cont body = "Device: ioS" + '/n' + "Phone Number:6756777" + '/n'

Comment: Later I found that it is an open bug with the new iOS.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681023